# Can Svelte compiler correctly handle standard JavaScript and HTML too (without using any Svelte features)?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Can Svelte compiler correctly handle standard JavaScript and HTML too (without using any Svelte features)?
I need universal interface for creating simple components and I would like to give flexibility for users which can use only standard JavaScript and HTML and for users which can use Svelte features.

Comment: Why not just use [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)?

Comment: Because trying to author non-trivial web components by hand is a soul-sucking experience. @Fox what do you mean 'handle standard JavaScript and HTML'? Valid HTML is already valid Svelte, and you can already put whatever JavaScript you want inside the `<script>`. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.